# Firebase onDisconnect().removeValue() always deletes value even while client is connected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a presence system in my `FirebaseDatabase` and in my Android app that I am developing. Currently, i am trying to implement the `onDisconenct()` method on my database.

```
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
dbRef.child("users").child("customers").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).onDisconnect().removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference firebase) {
            if (error != null) {
                System.out.println("could not establish onDisconnect event:" + error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The firebase JSON tree is structured as such

```
APP>
 USERS>
  CUSTOMERS>
   UID-
```

The biggest problem I have now is that `onDisconnect().removeValue()` is always executed when the `Activity` is created ( ie, data is created and then immediately deleted). This happens while the app is still connected to the database and authenticated.

EDIT:

Upon implementing this line of code

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
                dbRef.child("users").child("customers").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        }
```

It seems like the app is constantly connecting and disconnecting from the database...

Comment: The connection is automatically closed after about one minute if there are no pending writes and no registered listeners.

Comment: yeap guess youre right too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Guess i finally found the answer to my question. In case anyone faces this problem in the future...

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mUser.getToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        }
                    }
```

this line of recurring code caused my client to constantly connect and disconnect.